# Rails e simple_form, filtrar valores para preencher um combobox

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

Existem três tabelas, uma chamada **empresa**, outra **grupo** e uma chamada **subgrupo**, existe um campo ***empresa_id*** nesta duas, na ultima tem o campo ***grupo_id***, um formulário, neste form uso o simple_form para mostrar um combobox com os grupos, mas vem todos os grupos e preciso filtrar o grupos de cada empresa, como fazer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Respondendo a minha própria pergunta :-p

```
= f.association :group, 
                collection: Group.where('company_id = ?', current_user.company_id), selected: @subgroup.group_id
```